# Unable to update office365 Contacts using cURL

Tags: php, curl, office365

Even though by setting all the required headers and options I am not able to update contact record using cURL. The response from cURL is empty and cur_error() is also not showing any error.

Can any one suggest what's wrong in the below code?

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: you'll need to provide the contents of `$params` and `$headers` and if possible `$url` too

Comment: **$params** = {"GivenName":"test","Surname":"contact","Title":"","CompanyName":"","BusinessPhones":["2132323"]}  **$headers** = 
User-Agent: Office365Integration/1.0
client-request-id: $client_id
return-client-request-id: FALSE
authorization: Bearer $access_token
Accept: application/json
odata.metadata: full  **$url** = https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/contacts/{contact_id}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, making sure parameters are constructed correctly and adding a `Content-Type` header:

```
$data = array(
  "GivenName"   => "test",
  "Surname"     => "contact",
  "Title"       => "",
  "CompanyName" => "",
  "BusinessPhones" => array("2132323")
);
$params = json_encode($data);

$headers = array(
  "User-Agent: Office365Integration/1.0",
  "client-request-id: $client_id",
  "return-client-request-id: FALSE",
  "Authorization: Bearer $access_token",
  "Accept: application/json",
  "odata.metadata: full",
  "Content-Type: application/json"
);

$url = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/contacts/$contact_id";
```

Comment: Thank you @hans :) It worked. The mistake was with the header, I was creating header array in key and value format. ex: User-Agent => "Office365/1.0". This I replaced into "User-Agent: Offiece365/1.0" and it worked like a charm.